# insert url's to internet explorer back/forward

Tags: internet-explorer, back, forward

I'm writing an internet application,
and i would like to insert url's into the back/forward stack of the ie,
without actually sending the browser to those links.

is it possible???

Comment: What's the purpose of this? People wouldn't like their history being tampered with further than using javascript to send them back/forward.

Comment: I'm writing an application that uses ajax, and i would like to add an option for 'back' without adding another 'back' button inside my application

Answer (score 1):

In an ajax based page you can use the hash part of the url to enable navigation using the default forward and back buttons. For example: #tab1, #tab2, #tab3 to navigate through a tabbed wizard.

The hash change does not trigger a default postback, so the change of the hash has to be detected with javascript to trigger a function to get the desired information through ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Websites are not allowed to manipulate the travel log arbitrarily.  You can move back and forward through the travel log, and add to it by navigating the browser, but you cannot simply insert whatever you'd like without actually navigating there.

This is a security feature.  If websites could arbitrarily modify the travel log, they could insert all sorts of spam, advertising, lead generation sites, etc, and the user would no longer be effectively in control of the browsing experience.  The browser experience would no longer be consistent and predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is a good reason why this isn't possible!